# How can I run export NODE_OPTIONS=--openssl-legacy-provider in Webpack script?

Tags: node.js, npm, webpack

I have webpack script that triggers build

```
"buildProd": "webpack --config webpack.config.js --mode=production --display-error-details"
```

But it fails with error

```
 {
  opensslErrorStack: [ 'error:03000086:digital envelope routines::initialization error' ],
  library: 'digital envelope routines',
  reason: 'unsupported',
  code: 'ERR_OSSL_EVP_UNSUPPORTED'
}
```

I can fix this error manually typing

```
export NODE_OPTIONS=--openssl-legacy-provider
```

and all works fine

But I need to export NODE_OPTIONS in script for CI.
Is there any way to set NODE_OPTIONS in webpack script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `env` tool:

```
"buildProd": "env NODE_OPTIONS=--openssl-legacy-provider webpack --config webpack.config.js --mode=production --display-error-details"
```

Alternatively, set the option in your CI provider's (you're not telling us what you're using, so I can't help more specifically) environment variable settings.

Answer (score 2):

If you work on windows you can set it with `set`:

```
"buildProd": "(set NODE_OPTIONS=--openssl-legacy-provider) && webpack --config webpack.config.js --mode=production --display-error-details"
```

On Mac or Linux:

```
"buildProd": "NODE_OPTIONS=--openssl-legacy-provider webpack --config webpack.config.js --mode=production --display-error-details"
```